# How to determine if I have a pointer to released object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

In a function I am processing an object which may be corrupted sometimes, at runtime, can I somehow determine whether or not my object is corrupted?

Answer (score 6):

The only way to really do this is to leverage a new thing with ARC (and iOS 5, doesn't work before this) called `__weak` pointers.

It should also be noted that `__weak` variables do not retain, by definition. If a `__weak` variable retained it's target, then by definition, it couldn't release itself.

Basically, a `__weak` pointer is a variable that automatically set's itself to `NULL` when it is deallocated. Thus, you can do something like this to determine if an object is deallocated:

```
__strong id object; // required so that the object doesn't get deallocated right away
__weak id _weakRef;

object = [NSObject new];
_weakRef = object;

// do stuff with 'object'

if (_weakRef)
{
    // 'object' hasn't been deallocated yet, do something with it.
}
```

Normally speaking, you don't hold onto a strong and weak reference to an object, however, as this causes `_weakRef` to be useless (just check when you set `object` to `nil`).

I would also caution against having a design pattern based solely on `__weak` variables, especially if you are making a framework. Nothing says 'Annoying' like having to use iOS 5 as your target deployment.

I hope this post helped you get a deeper understanding of how weak references work, and if not, there is an excellent wikipedia article you can read here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference

Comment: +1 as being the only correct answer to the many duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no, there's no way to tell if your object has been deallocated.  For more explanation, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7797817/3009).

Comment: I'm -1'ing this, because it doesn't take into account ARC and new `__weak` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that object is an `NSObject`, just enable Zombies in Instruments. Then all you have to do is message the object in question. It will let you know if the object is dead when you message it.